# ui-date update options dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, uidatepicker

I am using Angularjs ui-date to bind Jquery datepicker. I have two date pickers in my page named as start and end.

I would like to change the end date's starting value based on the start date. Is there anyway to change options of datepicker dynamically.

For EX:

StartDate: 7th Sep,2013
End Date should have the min date as 8th Sep,2013.

Answer (score 3):

I've just faced the same issue, this is what I have done:

Let's say you have the following html

```
<div ng-controller="MyDateCtrl">
    <input ui-date="fromDatePickerOptions" type="text" ng-model="date.from" />
    <input ui-date="toDatePickerOptions" type="text" ng-model="date.to" />
</div>
```

Then in your JS you would have something like:

```
function MyDateCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.date = {
        from: new Date(),
        to:   new Date()
    };

    $scope.fromDatePickerOptions = {
      dateFormat: 'M dd, yy'
    };

    $scope.toDatePickerOptions = {
      dateFormat: 'M dd, yy'
    };

    $scope.$watch('date', function() {
      // You could offset dates however you like according to your needs.
      // Here, start cannot be after end and of course end cannot be before start.
      $scope.fromDatePickerOptions.maxDate = $scope.date.to,
      $scope.toDatePickerOptions.minDate   = $scope.date.from;
    }, true);
}
```

The `true` second argument of `$watch()` just compares object for equality rather than for reference according to the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch).)

The changes on `$scope.fromDatePickerOptions` and `$scope.toDatePickerOptions` will make ui-date directives to reload their options.

That's it! This worked fine for me.